# can't find the mysql database in docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I specify a volume for myself in the docker-compose.yaml but nothing appears in this directory.  I can connect to the db from mysql workbench and via nodejs 
npm package "mysql": "^2.15.0".

I can stop the docker containers and restart them and the db is persisted. If I restart my PC, the db disappears and it needs to be recreated.

Q: What is the correct way to specify a location for the mysql db in a docker-compose.yaml file so the db is persisted?

My environment is a windows pc running docker Version 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762).

My docker-compose.yaml is as follows:

```
mysql-purple:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: purple
    ports:
      - "3308:3306" # externaly use 3308 example mysql workbench localhost: 3308)
    volumes:
      - "C:/Users/john_/Documents/mySQLdatabases:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with docker on windows, check [Volumes from docker-compose file no longer working after a reboot](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584)

Comment: Same bug? Maybe.  The mount to a windows directory never works for mysql even after some time.  If I docker exec -it xxxx /bin/bash and list the sql directory, I see the mysql files but these files do not appear in the windows directory.  So the mount occurs to some other location.  vs the bug, where the mount is supposed to be ok after some time.  Either way, very similar and scary that this bug is open for almost a year.